Replacing template in a string with a regular expression
I study regular expressions using examples
I have a string in which there are such occurrences in the string
..."resSec":{"entry":{"key":"mem","value":"7397920259"},"entry":{"key":"core","value":"1806132"}},"preemRes"...

or
..."resSec":{"entry":{"key":"mem","value":"7397920259"}},"preemRes"..

etc.
I need to exclude all cases similar to
"resSec":{"entry":{"key":"mem","value":"7397920259"},"entry":{"key":"core","value":"1806132"}},

I do it this way
String content2 = content.replace All("\"res Sec(.*)\\}\\},\"preemRes", "\"preemRes");
System.out.println(content2);

It seemed to me that everything that fits the template should be cut out according to the template (.*), but I get something completely different
Tell me, where is my mistake in the regular expression?

You seem to be using regular expressions for JSON. Why?

yes it was a json file but a corrupted json file
so I can't process it as json in its original form

How has it been corrupted? Perhaps the corruption can be avoided or reversed, and then the data can be extracted as valid JSON, which is a much more robust way to handle data.

I have no way to fix this file, it comes in this form
I have other json files and I am successfully processing them as json
That is my question is not related to the fact that I do not know how to process json...

We need another this but for json.

I tend to agre with @HovercraftFullOfEels. Regex is not a tool for this job. For one thing, regex is not good at handling nesting

I'm not sure what you exactly want, but I guess something like:
content.replaceAll("\"resSec(.*?)\\}\\},\"preemRes", "\"preemRes")

